# Area 51 Movie proposal - over the line by a sock puppet (or two)

Tags: support, area-51, commitment-phase, sock-puppets

I noticed that the movie proposal is now at 100% and I thought "that's nice", considering they managed to do it with only 201 commitments which is a reasonable achievement.

However, when I [looked at the recent commitments](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3698/movies) it seems a couple of users were more keen than others and decided to commit twice.

I'm not sure if this can be rolled back, but in the interest of fairness...

Also, is there not something in Area 51 that stops this type of sock puppetry from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like an accident.  I've merged the dupe accounts and it's still at 100%.

Comment: The [new Mathematica proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37304/mathematica) had a small accident today too: ArgentoSapiens and user49764 are the same flair. ArgentoSapiens is the account he uses on SO - could these also please be merged? Given the circumstances surrounding the Mathematica proposal and the higher activity bar we have effectively been asked to clear relative to other proposals such as Poker and Keyboard Shortcuts, I would not want there to be any questions about the extent of support for the proposal. So could this account duplication please be fixed?

Comment: @Verbeia I've merged the two accounts